# SqlAlchemy Table and Query Issues

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Still wrapping my head around SqlAlchemy and have run into a few issues. Not sure if it is because I am creating the relationships incorrectly, querying incorrect, or both.

The general idea is...

1. one-to-many from location to user (a location can have many users but users can only have one location).
2. many-to-many between group and user (a user can be a member of many groups and a group can have many members).
3. Same as #2 above for desc and user.

My tables are created as follows:

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

group_user_association_table = Table('group_user_association_table', Base.metadata,
                           Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('group.id')),
                           Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')))
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    users = relationship('User', secondary=group_user_association_table, backref='group')

desc_user_association_table = Table('desc_user_association', Base.metadata,
                            Column('desc_id', Integer, ForeignKey('desc.id')),
                            Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')))

class Desc(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'desc'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    users = relationship('User', secondary=desc_user_association_table, backref='desc')

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.id'))
    groups = Column(String, ForeignKey('group.id'))
    descs = Column(String, ForeignKey('desc.id'))
    location = relationship('Location', backref='user')
```

Here are some examples as to how I am creating the data (all being scraped from the web):

```py
location = Location(id=city[1], name=city[0]) #city = ('name', id)
profile = User()
profile.id = int(str(span2class[0].a['href'][7:]))
profile.user_name = str(span2class[0].a.img['alt'])
profile.location_id = location.id

g = Group(id=gid, name=str(group.contents[0])) # add the group to the Group table
self.db_session.add(g)
# Now add the gid to a list that will be added to the profile that eventually gets added to the user table
profile.groups.append(str(gid)) # stick the gid into the list
profile.groups = ','.join(profile.groups) # convert list to csv string
# Repeat basically same thing above for desc

self.db_session.add(profile)
self.db_session.commit()
```

As far as queries go, I've got some of the basic ones working such as:

```py
for instance in db_session.query(User).all():
    print instance.id, instance.user_name
```

But when it comes to performing a join to get (for example) group.id and group.name for a specific user.id... nothing I've tried has worked. I am guessing that the form would be something like the following:

```py
db_session.query(User, Group).join('users').filter(User.id==42)
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Why are there `groups` and `descs` columns on the `User` table?

Comment: @van Not really sure. Probably left over from before I tried to get the relationship working. That or I saw it in one of the examples I referenced to try to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Joins works from left to right, so you should join on the relationship from `User` to `Group`:

```
db_session.query(User, Group).join(User.group).filter(User.id == 42)
```

But this return you a list of tuples `(<User>, <Group>)`, so if the user belongs to 2 or more groups, you will receive 2 or more rows.

If you really want to load both the user and its groups in one (`SQL`) query, a better way would be to load a user, but configure query to preload groups:

```
u = (session.query(User)
     .options(joinedload(User.group))
     .get(42)
     )

print("User = {}".format(u))
for g in u.group:
    print("  Group = {}".format(g))
```